# Making Query's Result #1 As First Added?

Tags: php

Basically I have this function that is meant for my forum where it gets all the replies to a certain topic. The problem is it will echo the latest reply first, and it will display the first reply last.

Does that make sense?

I basically want this to be backwards.

```
    function getReply($id){
        $q2 = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `reply` where `reply_id`='$id'");
        if(!$q2){
            echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
        }
        echo '<ul class="list-group">';
        while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
            echo '<center><br />
  <div class="container">
      <li class="list-group-item">
   '.$res2['reply_content'].'
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
                    Posted By <strong><a href="../public.php?id='.$res2["reply_by"].'">'.getOwner($res2['reply_by']).'</stong></a>
                    on <strong>'.$res2['reply_date'].'</strong><br />
</li>
</div>';
        }   
}
```

Comment: `order by` in your query? (that is too small for an answer, so I added it as a comment…)

Comment: What kind of field is `reply_date`?

Comment: I could try ordering by reply_id but that wouldn't work. What would I order by?

Comment: by a post id? Don't you have some auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: No, would I need to in order to do this? I could add it but is there any point?

Comment: @KevinHarrison how do you actually address the single rows if you want to edit them?

Comment: What do you mean "edit"? And I added an auto-incrementing column to the table but if I order by that then it would still be in order, I want it going backwards do you know what I mean?

Comment: How do you call this function `getReply`? Where does `$id` come from? That's where you have to do the ordering.

Comment: getReply($id) and $id is equal to the id of the topic they're viewing.

Comment: Then the column should be named `topic_id`, not `reply_id`. To solve your problem you need to add an autoincrement `id` column to your table. Then `order by id` in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getReply($id){
    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM `reply` 
        WHERE `reply_id` = '$id'
        ORDER BY `id` ASC
    ";
    $q2 = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: One proble, the data doesn't save the hour or anything only day, month, year. So that wouldn't work.

Comment: Then use your primary-autoincrement field.

Comment: p.s. you said in the comments, that `reply_date` is DATETIME field, now you are saying that it is only DATE field?

Comment: As I said before if I order by that then it will order it in the right order thats the opposite of what I want. Sorry, I didn't notice it was date I will change to datettime.

Comment: But that is what you requested in the question: `The problem is it will echo the latest reply first, and it will display the first reply last.` ... If you wish to reverse the order, then use `ORDER BY id DESC` instead of `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Comment: That is ordering it from greatest to least though. It should be least to greatest. ASC worked perfectly.